# KDE Recent Documents *only* (Not Locations)

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-5, dolphin-file-manager

In KDE Plasma 5, the "Recent Documents" item in the Application Menu includes both Recent Documents, and Recent Locations (i.e. shows not only recent documents, but also all the folders I've browsed to in Dolphin). Is there a way to disable the "recent locations" behavior, so it shows *only* recent documents (i.e. similar to how it behaves on Windows)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a great solution, but after a month of trying & posting in half a dozen different places (here, official KDE forums, KDE bug tracker, etc), the best I can come up with is:

```
 sqlite3 ~/.local/share/kactivitymanagerd/resources/database "DELETE FROM ResourceScoreCache WHERE initiatingAgent = 'dolphin';" ; pkill -f kactivitymanagerd ; /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kactivitymanagerd &
```

If you create a launcher item with this command, you can run it to delete all the clutter from the menu prior to using it. The menu will therefore temporarily appear as though it were behaving properly (aka "Recent Documents" will actually show recent documents).  It will of course continue to become cluttered again as you navigate around the filesystem, but at least it provides a one-off way to simulate a more sane behavior.